# How to insert data in database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the below query to insert data into a MySQL database. But this not working.
I'm also using this type query in my other page and that's working fine.

This is the SQL query:

```
$query="INSERT INTO `add7ras_work`.`movies` (`url`, `title`, 'description') 
VALUES ('$url','$title', '$desc');";
$result=mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: "But this is not working".  Any error messages you can share?

Comment: What doesn't work? #What error do you get? What have you done to troubleshoot this?

Comment: I need a copy and paste canned response for PDO/MySQL related...  Use PDO.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980792/php-pdo-mysql-queries

Comment: @ficuscr: Well, [here you go](https://gist.github.com/MadaraUchiha/3881905).

Answer (score 6):

You used single quotes around `description` instead of backticks:

```
$query="INSERT INTO `add7ras_work`.`movies` (`url`, `title`, `description`) VALUES ('$url','$title', '$desc');";
```

<sup>Standard disclaimer: Read up on PDO and MySQLi as `mysql_x` functions are deprecated.</sup>

Comment: Nice catch. Maybe a good reason why MySQL shouldn't use backticks for column name quoting.

Comment: @siride Indeed, however are backticks absolutely necessary in cases like these? I take it that if one is going to use back ticks, they'd have to use them on ALL of them, or not use them at all?

Comment: Hi...Thanku so much....

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'd advise to use them always, just to have consistent code and prevent errors caused by using a keyword as column name.

Comment: @Sirko I agree 100% --- When in doubt in accidentally or unknowingly using a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

Comment: Can you give the code for play  videos.The url of videos stored in my mysql db

Comment: @febeena That is a completely different problem. Anyways, on SO we expect you to do some research first and try yourself. If you fail, you're welcome to open another question, showing your code and where you failed.

Answer (score 1):

Bad quoting:

```
$query="INSERT INTO `add7ras_work`.`movies` (`url`, `title`, 'description') 
                                                             ^--         ^---
```

`'` quotes in SQL turn the quoted data into a string. This means you're using a string in a fieldname context, which does not work.