# Unable to retrieve query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I cant retrieve value from database. Below is my query

```
<?php
        $latestcover = queryTable("SELECT id, filename, title, thumbnail FROM borneo_ezone ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
        foreach ($latestcover as $key){
            echo '<p><a href="'.$key[1].'"><img src="'.$key[3].'" alt="Borneo Ezone '.$key[0].'" /></a></p>';
            echo '<p class="more">'.$key[0].'th issue of Borneo Ezone. <a href="'.$key[1].'">Read more &raquo;</a></p>';
        }

  ?>
```

Receive warning for PHP deprecated. How can I use mysqli to retrieve the query.

this my queryTable function

```
function queryTable($ask){

$query = mysqli_query($dbhandler,$ask); //query the db
$resArr = array(); //create the result array

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { //loop the rows returned from db
    $resArr[] = $row; //add row to array
}
return $resArr;
```

}

Comment: What you really want, is to skip `mysqli` and use [PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6981200/3504007)

Comment: There're millions of `mysqli` tutorials in the internet. No one will write another one for you here.

Comment: Why you need to use `ORDER BY` when you using `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: @DD77 Because the OP wants the record with the highest ID?

Comment: @u_mulder dont bother to comment if you wont help..

Comment: you have a variable scope issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$latestcover = "SELECT id, filename, title, thumbnail FROM borneo_ezone ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($latestcover)) {


    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
       echo '<p><a href="'.$row[1].'"><img src="'.$row[3].'" alt="Borneo Ezone '.$row[0].'" /></a></p>';
            echo '<p class="more">'.$row[0].'th issue of Borneo Ezone. <a href="'.$row[1].'">Read more &raquo;</a></p>';
    }
    $result->close();
}
```

try this code