# Beginner at PHP syntax, mySQL_query error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm attempting to make a page that is just a CREATE VIEW using DreamWeaver CS5. How do I need to input my code to just receive a table with all data relevant to the logged in user.

```
mysql_query(
CREATE VIEW UserResults
AS 
   SELECT E.No, E. Description
      , Count(R.RID WHERE $Username= R.Owner)
      , Count(R.RID WHERE $Username= R.Owner AND Status==’Active’ )
   FROM ETable AS E, RTABLE as R
   ORDER BY E.No)
```

Comment: your sql is vulnerable to sql injection attacks fyi.

Comment: You also shouldn't generally be creating views from code -- just like tables, they stay around once they're created, so you should only have to create them once when your application is installed.

Answer (score 3):

You have to put your query in quotes to make it a string.

```
mysql_query("CREATE VIEW UserResults AS SELECT E.No, E. Description, Count(R.RID WHERE $Username= R.Owner), Count(R.RID WHERE $Username= R.Owner AND Status==’Active’ ) FROM ETable AS E, RTABLE as R ORDER BY E.No")
```

Answer (score 1):

Daniel is correct about the quotes.  However, you should probably take a look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), the mysql_ functions are a bit outdated. You can read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866860/mysql-vs-pdo).

Answer (score 1):

- You have an extra ending parenthesis, which should be removed
- Views should not have `ORDER BY`.
- The `WHERE` clause should not be in the middle of the `SELECT`, you will need to use a `CASE`.
- You are returning a Cartesian product instead of joining your tables together, this may provide more results than you want/expect.

The `R.RID` in the `THEN` block of the `CASE` statements may need to be a `1`, not entirely sure what you hoped to get from those `COUNT` statements you originally had.

I tried to figure out what you were trying to do, and I think this is it:

```
CREATE VIEW UserResults AS
   SELECT E.No, E.Description
      , SUM(CASE 
               WHEN $Username = R.Owner THEN R.RID
               ELSE 0
            END) AS SumOfOwner
      , SUM(CASE
               WHEN $Username = R.Owner AND Status = 'Active' THEN R.RID
               ELSE 0
            END) AS SumOfOwnerAndActive
   FROM ETable AS E
   INNER JOIN RTABLE as R ON E.No = R.ENo
   GROUP BY E.No, E.Description
```