# comparing Query results

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query1= mysql_query("select r.nid from ....");     

$query2= mysql_query("select t.nid from....");
```

Both these queries return a nid. How to compare the 2 returned nid are equal.. I'm just a beginner.

Comment: why do need it? you can compere then in query. Do you know how to get data from database using php? do you know how to compare 2 variables in php?

Comment: where do you like to make that compare? in php code or in sql?

Comment: If you're going to continue doing mysql using PHP (and just started learning) I highly suggest learning PDO instead of using mysql_* . Suggested Reads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866860/mysql-vs-pdo
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$row1 = mysql_fetch_row($query1);
$row2 = mysql_fetch_row($query2);
if($row1[0] == $row2[0])
{
//something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in pure sql. Like this:

```
select 
    r.nid 
from 
    ....
WHERE EXISTS
(
    select 
        NULL 
    from
        ....
    WHERE
        t.nid = r.nid 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are certainly sure that the query really returns one id, you can speed up checking it by:

```
$query1 = mysql_query("select r.nid from ...."); 
$query2 = mysql_query("select t.nid from ...."); 
if(mysql_fetch_field($query1, 0) === mysql_fetch_field($query2, 0))
{
    //do something
}
```