# Issue with mysql_real_escape_string()

Tags: php, mysql, string, escaping

I began learning to code a few days ago and I am having some issues with mysql_real_escape_string, specifically with a login.php.

The error messages:

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'elegant'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/elegant/public_html/php/login.php on line 3

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the     server could not be established in /home/elegant/public_html/php/login.php on line 3

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'elegant'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/elegant/public_html/php/login.php on line 4

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/elegant/public_html/php/login.php on line 4
Please enter a username and a password
```

Here is the code I have so far -- this code worked in localhost but once I put it online and imported the database tables, it gave me some issues:

```
<?php

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

if ($username&&$password)

{

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","elegant_root","password;1") or die("Couldn't             connect!");
mysql_select_db("elegant_ezworkstation") or die("Couldn't find database");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=$username");

$numrows = mysql_numrows($query);

if ($numrows!=0)
{

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{

    $dbusername = $row['username'];
    $dbpassword = $row['password'];

}

if ($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword)
{

    echo "You're in";

}
else
    echo "Incorrect password!";

}
else
die("That user doesn't exist");

}

else
die("Please enter a username and a password");

?>
```

EDIT: I changed to mysqli and I got these errors:

```
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/elegant/public_html/php/login.php on line 3

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/elegant/public_html/php/login.php on line 4
```

Comment: You need `mysql connection` before you call `mysql_real_escape_string` ... put it after the connection `mysql_connect`

Comment: Rewrite your code and use `mysqli_()`

Comment: If you're learning to code, don't learn from any tutorials that use mysql.... look for tutorials that use mysqli or (better still) PDO

Comment: I'm wondering what resource you're using that sent you down the path of using `mysql_query` in 2012.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no
 longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation
 process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red
 box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared
 statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either
 [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you
 can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you.
 If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting `mysql_real_escape_string()` after you connect to the db will work fine.

However, you should shift to mysqli or PDO. MySQL is deprecated now.
A few links to help you out

1. [Moving from mysql to mysqli or pdo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770782/moving-from-mysql-to-mysqli-or-pdo)
2. [mysqli or PDO - what are the pros and cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons)

The equivalent commands in mysqli and PDO for escaping would be `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and `PDO::quote()` respectively.

As people are pointing out, PDO is definitely the better alternative. Here is an answer I previously wrote comparing PDO with others.

[PDO - real facts and best practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277675/pdo-real-facts-and-best-practice/11277786#11277786)

And another advantage of this will be that you don't need to use escaping functions if you use prepared statements with named parameters.

Comment: The thing about PDO and `mysqli` is you really don't need to use the SQL escaping functions directly if you use placeholders, which is really the *only* way to be safe.

Comment: I edited it so that it is using mysqli_real_escape_string() but now I get these error messages: Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/elegant/public_html/php/login.php on line 3

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/elegant/public_html/php/login.php on line 4

Comment: Please go through the official documentation [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) and see what you are missing.