# PHP/SQL - Incorrect Syntax

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to MySQL Queries. This is what I have so far what did I do wrong?

```
"INSERT INTO users (ip) WHERE id = '".$_SESSION["user"]["id"]."' 
VALUES ('$ip')"
```

**EDIT**

I just was asking about how my syntax was wrong. I understand the vulnerabilities, and did not paste them in my question. I am using the PDO library and mysql_real_string_escape WHENEVER I can...

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Trying to take $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] and place it into the IP field of my database. I'm indicated which row to specify using the user's ID which corresponds with the ID's in the database if they are logged in.

Comment: `INSERT INTO ... WHERE`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

INSERT query is wrong. I think you are updating something and you need to use UPDATE query

```
UPDATE users SET ip = '$ip' WHERE id = '".$_SESSION["user"]["id"]."'
```

Also work on fixing sql injection attacks.

Comment: How would I go about fixing the SQL injection? mysql real string escape?

Comment: Yes, use mysql real string escape

Comment: use `PDO_MYSQL`, which is more safer than `mySQL`. [PDO_MYSQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) Also check this SO post form more info  [MySQL versus PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866860/mysql-versus-pdo)

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO users (ip) 
VALUES ('value to insert')
```

or

```
UPDATE users
SET ip = 'value to update'
WHERE ip = 'value to check'
```

Also, wrap your `value to update` and `value to insert` in a PHP `mysqli_real_escape_string($DB,$val)`

Answer (score 0):

```
  INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
  VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
  WHERE column_name operator value
```

[sql injection info](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)