# Returning AJAX Value to Javasscript variable

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I have spent hours looking for help with returning to Javascript the AJAX call to a php script.

What I am trying to do, is insert a value into a table, then return the id for that inserted row, which can then be used in a form, so when the time to update the table with the form data, it can specify where it should go (which row).  I need to do this, so I can basically reserve the row, and it won't be stolen by another user.

This is the call I have been using:

```
id = getID('<?php echo $q; ?>','<?php echo $i; ?>');
```

The php values are valid (looking at the code, the values are displayed), and the var is declared outside of the javascript function.

This is the AJAX function:

```
var xmlhttp;

function getID(q, i)
{
    xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
  if (xmlhttp==null)
  {
    alert ("Sorry but your browser does not support AJAX or Javascript has been disabled");
    return;
  }

  var url = "getID.php";

  url = url + "?q=" + q;
  url = url + "&i=" + i;

  // execute the fully formed request
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
  xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
}


function stateChanged()
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
  {
      id = xmlhttp.responseText;
//    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
//    return xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}


function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  return null;
}
```

and the php code:

```
$q  = $_GET['q'];
$i = $_GET['i'];

$query = "INSERT INTO parts (q, i) VALUES ('".$q."','".$i."')";

$results = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$nextId = mysql_insert_id();
echo "$nextId";
```

If I alert the value, it will return properly, but in the form, which is creating a DOM dynamic row for this value and data to be entered, it comes up with "undefined".  Can anyone guide me how to make this work?  I will admit I'm no AJAX expert, and I can't seem to get callbacks to work when I try them, and frankly, don't really understand how...

Thank you in advance for any help anyone can offer.

Comment: use `echo json_encode` in your php script

Comment: general comments: use jQuery and PDO

Comment: Can you tell me where to use that?  In the PHP in place of echo?

Comment: @Songo, can you be so kind as to offer some code to make it work?

Comment: @DrixsonOseña adding that in the PHP code results in no difference.  Still undefined.  `echo json_encode($nextId);`

Comment: @WillSam check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866860/mysql-versus-pdo) for why PDO is better to use than `mysql_*` extension and [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example) for using jQuery to do Ajax. Hope it helps as a starting point ;)

Comment: @WillSam Sorry my bad I forgot to ask you what type of data are you retrieving? json or just text?? if json use `json_encode(array('next_id' => $nextId));` or if just text then your script is just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know its little bit tough to understand the Ajax call method for ajax Newbies,
So here i would recommend to do this with Jquery .post ajax calling method !

here is the way of doing it,

*using jQuery .post() function*

you can pass data to any external php file via this function and get the output. 
(it automatically makes the ajax call to the remote php file)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
        $.post("getID.php",
        {
          q:"some data", // here set the variables you want to pass as $_POST
          i:"some data"     // here set the variables you want to pass as $_POST
        },
        function(data,status){
          alert("PHP file Output: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
          // here take the the php file output using the "data" variable , "status" is optional  
        });
      });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <button>Send an HTTP POST request to the php file and get the result back</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

PHP file :

```
<?php
$q  = $_POST['q'];
$i = $_POST['i'];

$query = "INSERT INTO parts (q, i) VALUES ('".$q."','".$i."')";

$results = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$nextId = mysql_insert_id();
echo "$nextId";

?>
```

Comment: I only have two small issues with this.  The first time I trigger it, I get "undefined" in the field I want to put it into in the form.  For every other time I trigger it (for a new row), it's filling in the value.  EDIT - other issue...I missed the POST instead of GET.  If you have any advice...I'm going to see what I can figure out on my own in the meantime.  Thanks again!

Comment: @WillSam issue 1 : if you can share the code which you use for the form updating, It'll be easy to find the issue !

Comment: Thanks, but I got it by calling the function and passing "data".  It's working great now.  Thanks!