# MySQL error in PHP for SEO slug

Tags: php, mysql, seo

I have a page named details.php. Here is its code:

```
<?
$id = $_GET['id'];
?>

<?
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `db` WHERE id = $id ");
while($db = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
?>

<p><?=$db['title']?> <br /> <?=$db['desc']?></p>
<? } ?>
```

So when I open in browser /details.php?id=1 it works. The paragraph tag shows me the information from id 1. So...

If I replace id with title, it will look like:

```
<?
$title = $_GET['title'];
?>

<?
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `db` WHERE title = $title ");
while($db = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
?>

<p><?=$db['title']?> <br /> <?=$db['desc']?></p>
<? } ?>
```

If I type in browser /details.php?title=M (M is an existing column in mysql), it doesn't work. I got this error in paragraph: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mario\game.php on line 51

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Firstly, don't use short open tags as this can confuse your server (eg, when you start working with XML) and is non-standard. Secondly, sanitise your input.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `db` WHERE title = '" . $title . "'");
```

`$title` is a string so in query you have to wrap it in single quotes

This(`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used. Switching to `PreparedStatements` is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Comment: Deleted my comment . :) **+1**

Comment: @JohnSmith `PDO's` advantage is that it is supported many detabases. For more details see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866860/mysql-versus-pdo

Comment: @crypticous and if I apply with PDO's will protect me against SQL injection?

Comment: @JohnSmith See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: @JohnSmith With prepared statements you can