# Using one parameter multiple times in prepared mysqli-statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, param

Is it possible to use one parameter in a prepared **mysqli**-statement multiple times with **only binding it one time**?
something like this

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare(SELECT * FROM user WHERE age BETWEEN ?1 - 2 AND ?1 + 2);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $myAge);
```

I think this is possible with `PDO`, but I don't konw how to do this with `mysqli`.

Comment: That's not possible with plain PDO either.

Comment: Unfortunately no. PDO has named parameters; while MySQLi does not. As such you'll need to bind it twice.

Comment: Ok. So I realy have to bind the parameters multiple times. Its no problem but I thought there ist a nicer way to do this.

Comment: You can do this with named parameters in PDO, but only when PDO is configured to emulate prepares.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to close the question:

The answer is **no**.

If you want to bind a parameter only one time *and* using it multiple times in a query you have to use PDO and this maybe also needs a special configuration.

But there seems to be more reasons to use PDO instead of mysqli, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/368990/3440545) great answer or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/866868/3440545).

But sure there are workarounds. See the other answers to this question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this instead

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare(SELECT * FROM user WHERE age BETWEEN ? - 2 AND ? + 2);
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $my_age, $my_age);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP 8.1 you can use execute without bind_param. I am using array_fill to do the trick.

```
$stmt->execute(array_fill(0, 1, $myage));
```

You can edit the array_fill values depending on the statement, Suppose you have 3 values to fill, you can use:

```
$stmt->execute(array_fill(0, 2, $myage));
```