# PHP Can not import a global variable into a function that is inside a class

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I've a unlimited menu class based on php and mysql that found on stackoverflow. I've customized it for multilanguage web page. But when i'm trying to import a global variable into class, itgives me a warning;

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\path\menu.php on line 75

This is Sql query and `get_menu_items` function:

```
function get_menu_items()
        {
                global $lang;
                global $visibility;
                $sql = 'SELECT menu. * , menu_lang. * 
                FROM menu
                INNER JOIN menu_lang 
                ON menu.id = menu_lang.menu_id
                AND menu_lang.menu_lang_iso = '.$lang.'
                AND menu_lang.visibility = '.$visibility.'';
                return $this->fetch_assoc_all( $sql );
        }
```

And `$lang` variable coming from lang.php file. It looks like;

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
header('Cache-control: private');
if(isset($_GET["lang"])) {
    $lang = $_GET["lang"];
    $_SESSION["lang"] = $lang;
    setcookie("lang", $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
}
elseif(isset($_SESSION["lang"])) {
    $lang = $_SESSION["lang"];
}
elseif(isset($_COOKIE["lang"])) {
    $lang = $_COOKIE["lang"];
}
else {
    $lang = "tr";
    $_SESSION["lang"] = $lang;
    setcookie("lang", $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
}
ob_end_flush();
```

i signed warning line `75 TH LINE`, you can find it below;

```
function get_menu_html( $root_id = 0 )
        {
                $this->html  = array();
                $this->items = $this->get_menu_items();

                foreach ( $this->items as $item )
                        $children[$item['parent_id']][] = $item; // 75. LINE HERE

                $loop = !empty( $children[$root_id] );
....
```

If i change sql query without variables manuel values it works perfectly;

```
$sql = 'SELECT menu. * , menu_lang. * 
        FROM menu
        INNER JOIN menu_lang 
        ON menu.id = menu_lang.menu_id
        AND menu_lang.menu_lang_iso = "tr"
        AND menu_lang.visibility = '.$visibility.'';
```

What am i missing? Does my language script cant handle last else statement, or my `get_menu_items` function cant import `$lang` variable?

Any help will greatly appricated.

Comment: If you look at the generated SQL statement from the failing, and compare to the working, you'll seel that you're not quoting the `$lang` variable

Comment: Perhaps this is a good time to start learning about bind variables with MySQLi or PDO

Comment: @RowlandShaw thx for comment. but i'm using quotes on `$lang` variable --> `else {
    $lang = "tr"; // HERE
    $_SESSION["lang"] = $lang;
    setcookie("lang", $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
}`

Comment: Downvoter make sense and tell me why you downvoted? My question is quiet clear.

Comment: @MarkBaker do i need to `bind` all sql queries even doesnt contains any `$_GET`values?

Comment: No you don't, but you should..... not only is it a good habit to get into, bind vars will be automatically escaped and quoted for you; they're actually easier to use than injected vars (as your problem here demonstrates), as well as being safer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

old school error of string concatenation of quotes `'`

```
  $sql = "SELECT menu. * , menu_lang. * 
          FROM menu
          INNER JOIN menu_lang 
          ON menu.id = menu_lang.menu_id
          AND menu_lang.menu_lang_iso = '".$lang."'
          AND menu_lang.visibility = '".$visibility."'";
```

**what it does**

this particular section : `'".$lang."'` will make sure that variable being fetched in query, is quoted with `'` quotes around it!

Also, upgrade to [better and secure way of doing things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866860/mysql-versus-pdo)

Comment: While it may be obvious to you, some people do not see the error. Please try to explain it.

Comment: @EduardLuca : while i was editing, post already got edited mate....i do not take *obvious* for consideration...explanation updated! :)

Comment: @HddnTHA : welcome...meanwhile, your code is prone to injection, please use `mysqli_` or `PDO` for better security! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor do i need to `bind` all sql queries even doesnt contains any `$_GET` values?

Comment: @HddnTHA : Mark answered your query above! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor Haha :) yes i noticed. Thank you so much anyway!