# Shopping cart not displaying products, intval?

Tags: php, html

I am creating a PHP shopping cart linked to SQL database, from a tutorial i am following.

The code below SHOULD display all my products, however I believe that the

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
```

section is messing it up. The SKU's of the products are Varchar, not integers, so I am lead to believe that this is causing the problem with "intval". Is there another datatype I can insert that will display my products again?

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == "add")
{
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);

    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]))
    {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity']++;
    } 
    else 
    {
        $sql2   = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE SKU={$id}";
        $query2 = mysql_query($sql2);

        if(mysql_num_rows($query2) != 0)
        {
            $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2);
            $_SESSION['cart'][$row2['SKU']] = array("quantity => 1, "price" => $row['price']);

        } 
        else 
        {
            $message = "This product id is invalid";
        }
    }
}
?>
<h2 class="message"><?php if(isset($message)){echo $message; ?></h2>
<h1>Product Page</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    $sql   = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY SKU ASC";
    $query = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Description']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "£" . $row['price']; ?></td>
            <td><a href="index.php?page=products&action=add&id=<?php echo $row['SKU']; ?>">Add to Cart</a></td>
        </tr>

        <?php
    }
    ?>

</table>
```

Comment: You should use prepared statements with PDO or mysqli instead of injecting variables in your sql statements.

Comment: You have a syntax error: `"quantity => 1,` must be `"quantity" => 1,`. You forgot a double quote

Comment: PHP makes very little distinction between numbers and strings.

There are many things wrong with this code. It doesn't follow many of the modern good practices. This tutorial is kinda bad.

I honestly can't tell you what this code does, it's too messy.

Comment: *Are* the product IDs integers? PHP doesn't care how your column type is defined it only cares what's in it.  Show us your DB table structure.

Comment: my product IDs are
test1, test2, test3
Unrealistic I know, but for the task they must remain strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) for `intval()` and you'll see that this method returns 0 when the variable isn't an integer.

if you're looking to search for this, you can just change the line to:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

to get the variable as a string

However there are two things to bear in mind with this:

- This is liable to lead to [sql injection vulnerabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) if not treated properly in your code
- The mysql_ functions are deprecated, and shouldn't be used in new code... there're a [number of good tutorials and debates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097245/php-mysql-v-mysqli-v-pdo) on the matter... use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: I have changed this section to what you suggested and it displays my products again.
However, it displays the $message "This product id is invalid"

Comment: what's in your DB?  is there actually an ID that matches your products?

Comment: The DB only holds SKU, Name, Description and price.
The 3 products all have the sku (test1, test2,test3)

Comment: And what are you passing to the page as the $_GET variables?

Comment: I'm trying to pass the SKU values

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an ending quote here:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$row2['SKU']] = array("quantity" => 1, "price" => $row['price']);
```

You're also missing a `}` sign

```
<h2 class="message"><?php if(isset($message)){echo $message; } ?> </h2>
```

Comment: Hi, I have added the quote after quantity, yet still no products are displayed